# Is it possible to access a value within and enum outside an enum

Tags: java, variables, enums, scope

For instance I have an Enum defined in another class,

EnumClasses.java and i can access that in different class fine by

```
    import java.io.DataInputStream;

    public class Thread1 extends Thread {

    declared variables here (variables not relevant)
    initiated variables here (variables not relevant)
    DataInputStream dis;

    }
    public void run() 
    {
        while (true)
        {
          try {
    int mesgType = dis.readInt(); 
            System.err.println(mesgType);

            switch (mesgType) {
    case EnumClasses.MYENUM:

    String data;
    data = myData;

    break;
                 } 
             }
         }
    }
```

I want know if it is possible to access the value is inside that ENUM outside of that ENUM.
E.g.

```
    public static void myMethod(){

    System.out.print(data);

    }
```

Is this possible or not possible, if possible how do I do it?

Comment: Your first piece of code seems to be just random snippets - it's really hard to tell what you're actually trying to achieve. If you could show a short but *complete* example, it would be considerably easier to help you...

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean but maybe this edit will help.,

Comment: I don't see any edit, and I definitely don't see a short but complete program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Well after the edit, that's still invalid (and badly formatted) code, as well as still not being a short but complete program. Please read http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints

Comment: *Sigh*, I was trying to keep it short, Let me see if i can fix it, to your satisfaction...

Comment: Short is good - but what part of syntax is `EnumClasses.MYENUM:` meant to be? I don't think I'm being unreasonable to ask for code that makes some kind of sense...

Comment: Posted comment down the bottom..

Comment: The whole thing is still *entirely* unclear to me. You haven't shown any declaration of `MyEnum`, and I still don't understand whether `data` is meant to be declared in there or somewhere else. Nice Cow's answer looks relevant, but if you think it's not then I'm even *more* confused about what you're looking for...

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the question rightly, it seems you wanted to somehow read what the `Enum` is about. One simple example, according to what I think you are asking is as follows:

```
enum Numbers {
    ONE ( 1, "One" ),
    TWO ( 2, "Two" );

    private int value;
    private String name;

    private Numbers ( int value, String name ) {
        this.value = value;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getValue () {
        return this.value;
    }

    public String getName () {
        return this.name;
    }
}

public class EnumExample {

    private void performTask () {
        System.out.println ( Numbers.ONE );
        Numbers numbers = Numbers.ONE;
        System.out.println ( "Value: " + numbers.getValue () );
        System.out.println ( "Name: " + numbers.getName () );
    }

    public static void main ( String[] args ) {
        new EnumExample ().performTask ();
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
C:\Mine\java\bin>java EnumExample
ONE
Value: 1
Name: One
```

Answer (score 0):

See this example on Enum :

```
public enum Level {
    HIGH,
    MEDIUM,
    LOW
}

public class Test
{
    public enum Status {
        Opened,
        Closed,
        Waiting
    }
}

public class abc {

    public static void main(String args[]) {            
        System.out.print(Level.HIGH);
        System.out.print(Test.Status.Opened);
    }
}
```

A good reference [Java Enums](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/enums.html)

Comment: Why would you nest `Status` within `Test`? It's not at all clear to me that this answers the OP's question... partly because the question is very unclear.

Comment: This answer is the closest though not quite right, I'm not sure how to edit the code anymore without bloating the webpage, I will give the exact error i get  : **The primitive type int of classname.Enum does not have a field data**, If this doesn't help you do suggest i just delete this because i cant full understand how to properly explain it in detail without bloating...

Comment: @CodeRequired - What I understand from your code now, is you want to access **data** variable outside of Enum Switch-Case. You are declaring **"String data;"** inside case statement then how it will be accessible outside of that scope. To have access to data variable, you can declare **"String data;"** at class level and then perform any assignments under case statement. Let me know if this helps?